# The senior Conservative declared in the new register of MPs’ interests that he will be paid £6,300 for eight hours of work

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The senior Conservative declared in the new **register of MPs’ interests** that he will be paid £6,300 for eight hours of work at Investcorp each month, or £788 an hour.

The whole sentence is shown above and what has made me confused is in **the new register of MPs' interests**. As far as I can tell, it is indicating for MPs' goods, but I can't confirm if I have the right understanding.

https://www.buzzfeed.com/alexwickham/this-former-defence-secretary-is-being-paid-ps788-an-hour?bftwuk&utm_term=4ldqpgm

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official page](https://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/standards-and-financial-interests/parliamentary-commissioner-for-standards/registers-of-interests/register-of-members-financial-interests/) of the UK Parliament

**Register of Members' Financial Interests**

> The main purpose of the Register is to provide information about any
>   **financial interest** which a Member has, or **any benefit which he or she
>   receives**, which others might reasonably consider to influence his or
>   her actions or words as a Member of Parliament.

You can check what is exactly registered following the link. The Register does not list all the goods of a member, just their financial interests and some extra payments that they may receive like the one that you mentioned.

Comment: There is scope for the word 'interests' to be misunderstood. In general it means any kind of business or personal financial arrangement from which a person benefits or hopes to benefit. It is not at all the same thing as interest paid on money that has been lent (although the entitlement to such interest could be a 'financial interest'). In the specific case of the Register referred to there are precise definitions as to what counts as a financial interest and what does not.